# Java persistence api not deleting / removing record oracle database 11g XE

Tags: java, oracle, api, jpa, persistence

I successfully created, merged, fetched records using Java Persistence API, but I'm not able to remove a record. I used em.createNativeQuery("Delete ...") and it worked fine, the problem is that I want to use the entity manager to do that. I think the problem could be with the oracle database, because I tried the above code with Derby and it worked fine.

```
 public void destroy(String id) throws NonexistentEntityException, RollbackFailureException, Exception {
    EntityManager em = null;
    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    utx = (UserTransaction) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/UserTransaction");
    try {
        utx.begin();
        em = getEntityManager();
        //Query query =  em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM SERVICIO WHERE SERVICIODESCRIPCION = '"+id+"'");
        //query.executeUpdate();
        Servicio servicio;
        try {
            servicio = em.getReference(Servicio.class, id);
            servicio.getServiciodescripcion();
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
            throw new NonexistentEntityException("The servicio with id " + id + " no longer exists.", enfe);
        }
        em.remove(servicio);
        utx.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception re) {
            throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.flush();
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work about it ? an exception occur or simple the record doesn't get deleted ?

Comment: The record doesn't get deleted, there are no error messages or exceptions in the glassfish server, I tried to see if the oracle database received the petition but i don't know how. I debugged the code and it retrieves the object from the context.

Comment: Also the primary key is a String, do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: Insert a log command here: `} catch (Exception ex) {
        try {   logger.log("An error occurred while trying to delete something", ex);
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception re) {` because at present you are unaware of any error, you are doing just rollback - and that's all, everything looks OK.

Comment: I just tried, nothing happens when i debbuged it nevers enter into the catch. I will change the primary key to a integer and i will post the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the problem was that the datatype of my primary key was set to a char(10), and I solved changing it to a VARCHAR(10), so in conclusion when working with an Oracle database, JPA and are primary keys set to text, the datatype that should be used is VARCHAR not CHAR, so the entity manager could work well. Thx.